# Shopping cart price rule does not seems to work with Magento 1.9.2

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules, shopping-cart, cart-rule

I have created multiple shopping cart rules & set "Stop Further Rules Processing" to Yes but that does not seems to work with Magento 1.9.2 only.

Multiple rules are applying currently by ignoring the "Stop Further Rules Processing", If anyone faced the related issue please help me to get it resolved. It will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you post here your complete rule information with screen shot?

Comment: Are you using Shopping cart rules and catalog rules or only shopping cart rules?

Comment: There used to be a bug related to further rules processing with Magento, not sure if it has been fixed in 1.9.2 but you should consider checking this one out: https://github.com/husseycoding/cartrulefix

Comment: Yes, i am using "shopping cart price rules" @Klettseb

Comment: @DigitalPianism you are getting it correct. I already used this but it did fixed for Magento 1.9.1 not 1.9.2